# creating or naming dataframes from list and performing "delta" measurements

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe that has this kind of format:

```
[timestamp][location code] [feature code][measurement]
```

meaning i can have something like:

```
TS                  LOC FEAT MEAS
2015-01-24 03:45:00 agb feat1 26
2015-01-25 04:00:00 agb feat1 27
2015-01-25 04:30:00 agb feat2 47
2015-01-17 12:00:00 fmq feat1 16
2015-01-18 12:00:00 fmq feat1 22
```

what i've done is use `pd.unique` and `tolist()` to get the names of the locations and store them on a list, but what i can't seem to figure out how to dynamically separate them into dataframes with the location code as the name of that dataframe.

i'd want to have for example a variable `agb` which is a dataframe like this:

```
2015-01-24 03:45:00 agb feat1 26
2015-01-25 04:00:00 agb feat1 27
2015-01-25 04:30:00 agb feat2 47
```

and a variable `fmq` which is a dataframe like this:

```
2015-01-17 12:00:00 fmq feat1 16
2015-01-18 12:00:00 fmq feat1 22
```

that i could create from iterating over the list of `LOC` and doing a `groupby` and `get_group`

and as a second part, i also can't seem to figure out (and unable to phrase the question well to look for answers here in stack overflow) how to produce the change in measurements.

for example in `fmq` i'd like to have another column `DEL` that is the difference between the measurements of the various features. something like:

```
TS                  LOC FEAT MEAS DEL
2015-01-17 12:00:00 fmq feat1 16  
2015-01-18 12:00:00 fmq feat1 22  6
```

would appreciate any help. thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this? you could just store the unique locations and use these to filter the df

Comment: @EdChum i failed to mention that my first fix for it was to store them in individual CSVs. (agb.csv, fmq.csv) and then access them later for my second part. was that what you're trying to propose? 
 
edit, adding this:
and that i was trying not to create any additional files so i posted the question.

Comment: for instance `locations = df['LOC'].unique()` will return an array of unique locations you can then use this to filter the df like `df[df['LOC']==locations[1]]`...etc

Comment: No I'm suggesting that it seems unnecessary to split the df based on location when you can easily filter the df like I've shown above

Comment: @EdChum oh okay. thanks, i'll try doing that. how about the second part though? the part where i need to get the difference in measurements of the features.

Comment: Use `diff` so `df['MEAS'].diff()` will give you what you want